# An error has occurred in (Workflow Name)

Tags: workflow, error

I have a workflow where it sends an email after the final approval. I noticed that sometimes the item is approved and the final email is not being sent. When I checked the status of it, I saw " An error has occurred in (Workflow Name) ".
There is nothing clear to investigate on. It just happened from time to time, like once or twice per month.

Comment: Did you check the hidden list "Workflow history" for the site?

Comment: where can I find this hidden list? @Papageno

Comment: It's on your site. Just add "/lists/Workflow%20History" to your url.

Comment: I got page not found @Papageno

Comment: There is a lot written about this list. Here is one example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/voyage/2015/01/23/where-is-workflow-history-list/

Comment: why I keep getting Page not found ): it tried to open it from SharePoint Designer / All Files but it is not there @Papageno